# Code does run on Netbeans but does not on Codechef compiler - it shows wrong answer

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author DELL
 */

public class Main {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

        int a[]=new int[20];

       Scanner kbd=new Scanner(System.in) ;
        //BufferedReader inp = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));

       //int test= Integer.parseInt(inp.readLine());
       int test=kbd.nextInt();
     while( test>0)
                {
    int fact=1;
    int n=kbd.nextInt();
    //int n= Integer.parseInt(inp.readLine());
    while(n>1)
        fact*=n--;
   System.out.print(""+fact);
       test--;

                }



 }
}
```

My code does not run on Codechef compiler when i submit it. It shows wrong o/p, yet it works fine on Netbeans.

Comment: There might be some specific TCs that might be failing

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using another class along with this class then remove access specifier "public" from both classes. And if not then please let us know what exactly is error.